# React + TS: How to use dot-notation components and generics at the same time?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a component `List` that has a sub-component `Title`, declared using dot-notation.

```js
type Item = {
  name: string;
  value: number;
};

type ListProps = {
  title: string;
  data: Item[];
};

export const List: React.FC<ListProps> & {
  Title: React.FC<{ title: string }>
} = ({ title, data }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <List.Title title={title}>
      <ul>
        {data.map((item) => (
          <li>
            {item.name}: {item.value}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

List.Title = ({title}) => <div>{title}</div>
```

And then i use this component:

```js
<List
    title="Stats"
    data={[
        { name: "strength", value: 30 },
        { name: "dexterity", value: 50 },
        { name: "intellect", value: 100 },
        { name: "vitality", value: 40 }
    ]}
/>
```

At this point everything is fine, but if i need to add generic type parameter to component and its interface it seems like there is no way to do this.

For example i want item name to be of certain type, that i can pass from parent.

```js
<List<"strength" | "dexterity" | "intellect" | "vitality">
    title="Stats"
    data={[
        { name: "strength", value: 30 },
        { name: "dexterity", value: 50 },
        { name: "intellect", value: 100 },
        { name: "vitality", value: 40 }
    ]}
/>
```

I know i can do it like this

```js
type Item<ItemName extends string = string> = {
  name: ItemName;
  value: number;
};

type ListProps<ItemName extends string = string> = {
  title: string;
  data: Item<ItemName>[];
};

export const List = <ItemName extends string = string,>({
  title,
  data
}: ListProps<ItemName>): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {data.map((item) => (
          <li>
            {item.name}: {item.value}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

// This isn't working, because `List` has no property `Title`
// List.Title = ({ title }) => <div>{title}</div>;
```

But in this case i don't know how i can specify type for `List.Title`. Is there any way to combine this two techniques?

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-violet-wvxo2g?file=/src/App.tsx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This isn't working, because List has no property Title

That's not the error TypeScript is raising in the Codesandbox (or in the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#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)). The error is *"Binding element 'title' implicitly has an 'any' type. (7031)"* That's because you haven't given any type for the props of `List.Title`. The `Title` props *used* to get a type from the type you'd given `List`, but since you've removed the explicit type annotation on `List`, you need to specify the type of `Title`'s `title` somewhere.

The simple change is to just specify it inline:

```
List.Title = ({ title }: {title: string; }) => <div>{title}</div>;
//                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#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) | [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-keldysh-r1u2cb)

Alternatively, you can do what you did in your first example and give `List` an explicit type. The type is:

```
{
    <ItemName extends string = string>({ title, data }: ListProps<ItemName>): JSX.Element;
    Title({ title }: {
        title: string;
    }): JSX.Element;
}
```

so:

```
export const List: {
    <ItemName extends string = string>({ title, data }: ListProps<ItemName>): JSX.Element;
    Title({ title }: {
        title: string;
    }): JSX.Element;
} = <ItemName extends string = string,>({/*...*/}) => {
    // ...
};
List.Title = ({ title }) => <div>{title}</div>;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4AocmATzCTgEkYkQAeJlgORRHqQA9mAOwAmAZzhiYUYEIDmcALyTpsuQD4lcAN7k4cITyQAuRsxDdeFfQDcUAGwCuJg45AAjJFAoBfClVp6ABlgKQAFHDAxdnNLPkEkUQkpGXktFLVNZV19GGAYexcM+Ws4ERQYFFMONhq49QBtAF1ffwFIWDg0CCEpOBCpUxz9OBiuIzgBYXEVVIVlYo0ACm04PIKkABoyipQ4H1MBmAiIKLGLI3UASlMAKQBlAA0AOgBRQt4hGFL9ABV8worNYA+gHHR6EaQ9aFUyLH77G5wB4vd4sRLfcg+LTnOKTBJJWZqdKqeSbdQrCHQrYQ8qVTGHULHSLROqXRHIt4fdFKTTDIgwRxQIRwJYQ-SsETAGzqMUjViOewyyGQ7S0lDPEAoMBLJb5FhXHki2XK0b2YBKk3K7R6kDPQy8MHW8zPOxOJA+Y3K1gAejNFpNVyuHpNPoV-tG3sl0ohV1alG93rgAEF7GIIHAAO7QADWYmM5COz3+Gy0QKpCMNEql6m0VJ8Pqj6lIQA)